# Acessing image from directory above

Tags: jsp

I have "axis2" folder in which there is "listServices.jsp" and folder called "include" containing "header.inc" and a folder "images" which contains images.The "listServices.jsp" makes the following call :

`<jsp:include page="include/header.inc" />`

and the header.jsp makes the following call:

`<td align="left"><img src="axis2/images/testImage.jpg"/></td>` The problem is that the testImage exists in "axis2/images/",however it is not displayed in the browser.I have tried to change the path to "../images/testImage.jpg" but it didn't work.

Comment: Give a screenshot of your project structure

Comment: `./images/testImage.jpg` for one folder back.

Comment: @SumeshTG isn't it two dots not justt one?

Comment: @Gordon Please include a screenshot of your project structure